# PostgreSQL query on a text column ignoring special characters

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which contains a text column, say vehicle number.

Now I want to query the table for fields which contain a particular vehicle number.

While matching I do not want to consider non-alphanumeric characters.

```
example: query condition - DEL123
         should match    - DEL-123, DEL/123, DEL@123, etc...
```

Comment: use regular expressions

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: @melpomene by special characters I meant characters which are not alphanumeric

Answer (score 8):

If you know which characters to skip, put them as the second parameter of this [`translate()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-string.html) call (which is faster than regexp functions):

```
select * 
from a_table
where translate(code, '-/@', '') = 'DEL123';
```

Else, you can compare only alphanumeric characters using `regexp_replace()`:

```
select * 
from a_table
where regexp_replace(code, '[^[:alnum:]]', '', 'g') = 'DEL123';
```

Comment: @kiln Thanks. It was helpful.

Comment: @SantoshGupta mind excepting this as answer? But I think this might accept more values than you really want.

Comment: @maxik - for example?

Comment: @klin He provided sample data of the form 'DEL[-/@]123' which suites his purpose. But what if another data contains 'DE-L@12-3'? This would also match using your solution but the author may not want it to be matched. Do not get me wrong, I really like your solution, but I want to point out that it might catch more than intended.

Comment: @maxik - your comments are welcome. I rely on what is written in the question. OP wrote: *While matching I do not want consider the special characters* and did not mention of any pattern.

Comment: @maxik though the examples are not very elaborate, but I wanted to to ignore special characters occurring at any position. Hence kiln's answer serves my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

@klin's answer is great, but is not sargable, so in cases where you're searching through millions of records (maybe not your case, but perhaps someone else with a similar question looking for answers), using regular expressions will likely render much better results.

The following will use indexes on code significantly reducing the number of rows tested:

```
select * 
from a_table
where code ~ '^DEL[^[:alnum:]]*123$';
```